# How can I check the length of the python code?

Tags: python, file, file-length

Is there a method to check the length of the CURRENT full code?

Similar to this:

```py
#The file is the current code, not an another
file = open("main.py", "r")
length_in_lines = file.linelength()
length_in_characters = file.chars()
```

If you know a similar method to solve this or fix the errors, on the code thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
file = open("main.py", "r")
length_in_lines = len(file.readlines())
file.seek(0)
length_in_char = len(file.read())
```

`readlines()` reads all the lines of the file in a list.

`read()` reads the whole file in a string.

The `len()` function returns the length of the argument.

Comment: This would not work for the file's number of characters. The file's pointer would be at the end of the file after reading the lines. It is necessary to `seek` the file's pointer to the beginning again.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open('script.py') as file:
    lines = len(file.readlines())
    file.seek(0)
    chars = len(file.read())

print('Number of lines: {}'.format(lines))
print('Number of chars: {}'.format(chars))
```

You would first get a list with all the lines, and getting the list's length (so, the number of lines), and then you would read the whole file as a string and count all the characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below for reading characters and lines of code.

```
file = open("main.py", "r")

print(len(file.readlines()))
print(len(file.read()))
```